# How to login name different than post author name wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there any way or plugin to change user's name different for post ([Post Author](http:////codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_author)) but login with its original username.

I have changed nickname from panel but its only change post author not its slug

My client don't want to show his username neither in post nor in the url for security reason. so i am looking for a way to do this job.

Thanks

Comment: You can simply change his nickname in the back end...

Comment: But its still showing in the slug

Comment: Hello, sorry for my delayed reply, if you edit your question with the php code of your _posted_on() function, i'll do my best to solve your issue. SYA.

Comment: Actually i am using theme and i did not write any custom code for this functionality i have changed nickname from panel and its what i was looking for but now i have one more issue with slug. the author page slug showing its original name so i am looking for way to change author name with slug too

Comment: This is why I'm asking you to reproduce the posted on function here ! This function contains most of the time the $byline variable, this is the variable that need to be changed for displaying only the nickname and not the nicename. So, whithout seeing what your function is asked to do, I can't suggest the correct changes to make. SYA.